# How to create a stacked bar for each group

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I have the following dataset:

```
SessionId    Query
   1           a   
   1           b
   2           a
   3           b
   3           b
   3           c
   3           a
```

I want to display a stacked bar chart where there will be a bar for each *Session* and the bar will consist of different colors for each *Query* that it has, the stacked size will be in the size of the number of queries in each session.

I tried something like this:

```
result = data.groupby('SessionId').apply(
   lambda group: (
      group.groupby('Query').apply(
         lambda queryGroup: (
            queryGroup.count()
         )                
      )
   )
 )
```

But it gives a weird table inside a table

Comment: You should group by both columns, and use the `.size()` aggregation (if I recall correctly). Then you'll have the data you need for the bar plot.

Comment: @Shovalt: this would look somethink like `data.groupby(['SessionId', 'Query']).size().unstack().plot.barh(stacked=True)`, I guess.

Comment: @stephan: exactly what I meant, I was on mobile and couldn't test :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) should do the job if I understand your question correctly:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'SessionId': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
                     'Query': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a']})

pd.crosstab(data.SessionId, data.Query).plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing one liner!

Comment: @Lee: yes, `crosstab` is sometimes quite useful. It is basically a wrapper around [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html). So you could get the same result with `pd.pivot_table(data, None, 'SessionId', 'Query', len).plot.barh(stacked=True)`, which is possibly a bit more efficient (but looks less nice).

Answer (score 0):

Pandas stacked bar chart relies on plotting different columns, so you'd need to pivot your data table to get the queries as columns holding the number of queries in rows.

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"session":[1,1,2,2,3,3],
              "query":list("ababab"), "count":[5,7,32,5,8,1]})
df.pivot("session","query").plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]